# How to print Array in react Component

Tags: reactjs, api

I want print Array in react Component thats component i am using from array. But getting error **Cannot find name 'row'.** i am usign react with material-Ui.  am using react with react material-Ui. Here i am getting error " **const suggestions = this.state.searchArray.data.map((row) => {
    return row.symbol;
  });**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from "./Autocomplete";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
const style = {
    flexGrow: 1
}



export class SearchScripComponent extends Component<any,any> {
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        searchArray:[],
        message: null
    }
    this.searchScripData = this.searchScripData.bind(this); 
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.searchScripData(this.requesDATA2());
}

requesDATA2()
{
   let data1= { "symbolOrName":"TATA"};
   return data1;
}

searchScripData(searchScrip: any) {
  ApiService.searchScripDataList(searchScrip)
      .then((res) => {
         this.setState({searchArray: res.data.data} )
      });

}
  render() {
    return (

<div>
const suggestions = this.state.searchArray.data.map((row) => {
    return row.symbol;
  });

<Autocomplete  suggestions={suggestions}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchScripComponent;
```

**What i want**

```
<Autocomplete  suggestions={row.symbol}/>
```

**my API DATA**

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "scripId": 299,
            "symbol": "TATAGLOBAL"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 520,
            "symbol": "TATAYODOGA"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 1195,
            "symbol": "TATASPONGE"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 30,
            "symbol": "TATASTLBSL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey ram, your question is not clear, in what you are using now you have an array of strings and in what you wanna achieve you are trying to access the symbol key that does not exist. could you please explain more.

Comment: @FarhaniWalid  i want print array data this here **<Autocomplete  suggestions={row.symbol}/>**

Comment: @FarhaniWalid   now i am getting data here   **<div>
  {this.state.searchArray.map((row: any) => (
  <div>{row.symbol}</div>
  ))}
  </div>**

Comment: can you add this array searchArray to your question

Comment: @FarhaniWalid comming from API

Comment: console.log(searchArray) and past it on the question so we can see what properties that have

Comment: @FarhaniWalid     {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "scripId": 299,
            "symbol": "TATAGLOBAL"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 520,
            "symbol": "TATAYODOGA"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 1195,
            "symbol": "TATASPONGE"
        },
        {
            "scripId": 30,
            "symbol": "TATASTLBSL"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @FarhaniWalid updated please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the api call you are iterating over the object that does not have a symbol proprety, so in your case you just need to change your map function like that

```
  const suggestions = this.state.searchArray.data.map((row) => {
    return row.symbol;
  });

<Autocomplete  suggestions={suggestions}/>
```

UPDATE

This is the working code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Autocomplete from "./Autocomplete";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
const style = {
  flexGrow: 1,
};

export class SearchScripComponent extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchArray: [],
      message: null,
    };
    this.searchScripData = this.searchScripData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.searchScripData(this.requesDATA2());
  }

  requesDATA2() {
    let data1 = { symbolOrName: "TATA" };
    return data1;
  }

  searchScripData(searchScrip: any) {
    ApiService.searchScripDataList(searchScrip).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ searchArray: res.data.data });
    });
  }
  render() {
    suggestions = this.state.searchArray.map((row) => {
      return row.symbol;
    });
    return <Autocomplete suggestions={suggestions} />;
  }
}

export default SearchScripComponent;
``
```

Comment: now i am getting error **Line 43:4:  Parsing error: Expression expected** i update my code in question please check whole code

Comment: you were declaring the const inside the return function, you had to declare it before it... i have updated my answer with the working code

Comment: Sorry for but now getting error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**.  really thank you

Comment: ApiService is a function that will call the api to get the data from there  when the user start typing on the autocomplete input ? ?

Comment: Now working fine i just remove **.data** from suggestions = **this.state.searchArray.data.map** updated code now **this.state.searchArray.map**

Comment: ah okey because you had already accessed the data property here       this.setState({ searchArray: res.data.data }); glad that this worked :)

Comment: you are Right sir